# Key mapping with the Shift button in PhpStorm

Tags: ide, editor, phpstorm, keymapping

I'm using **PhpStorm** and I am trying to setup/change some keymaps; however I can't seem to work out how to do it with the SHIFT keys.

I go into `Settings -> Keymap`

Then I right click on the one I want to change and select `Add Keyboard Shortcut`; after this is done I try using the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key in the `First Stroke` field but nothing happens - most other keys I tried appeared to work, but not shift!?

How can I get shift to work.

By the way, I am using Windows.

Comment: You cannot assign `Shift` alone (a modifier key) -- it has to be combo (e.g. `Shift+F1` etc). Same for `Alt` and `Ctrl`.

Comment: I'm not trying to, but I was trying to switch around the mapping for search everywhere and search files but wasn't having much luck.

Comment: *"I'm not trying to, but I was trying to switch around"* You are actually trying to do that. The default `2xShift` key for Search Everywhere is a special (hard coded?) case. You can assign another shortcut to bring Search Everywhere popup (which has no default combo assigned in keymap and still works) .. but you cannot re-use that shortcut for any other action.

Comment: Well that's a shame. :(

Comment: In any case: try describing the actual root of the problem: why do you need to make such switch? There may be (should be) some other ways of resolving the root issue.

Comment: I wanted to make the switch because double shift is far easier to press than ctrl + shift + n - when I'm searching for something 90% of the time it's probably going to be a file so makes sense to bind it to the easier key binding. :)

Comment: In such case you should consider another easy to use shortcut (e.g. `Ctrl+|` -- at least on my UK English keyboard they are next to each other so it's easy to press them). Another *possibly available* option: Search Everywhere allows to turn on or off the search scopes (what sort of entities to search/show) -- see if you can permanently disable unwanted types so that files will be the default (top) entries in the results list.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions :)